# Using Try out of Exception contexts

Tags: scala, error-handling

Is it in Scala acceptable to use `Try` (`Success`/`Failure`) outside of an actual `Exception` context as a return type of a function that can succeed or fail?

Comment: Why not use `Option` ?

Comment: Could you please share an example on how you want to use it? - Anyways, I agree with Mario that you may be better defining your own **ADT**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instances of `Try`, are either `Success` or `Failure`, where [`Failure`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/36096241b00873f88dbc9c81281c2be13919fa59/src/library/scala/util/Try.scala#L215) is

```
case class Failure[+T](exception: Throwable)
```

Note how `Failure` must be constructed with `Throwable`, so I think `Try` is meant to be used within context of `Throwable`s. So we cannot do something like

```
def foo: Try[Int] = {
  Failure(42) // Error: type mismatch; found : Int(42) required: Throwable
}
```

Consider using `Either` instead of `Try` outside exceptions context.

---

Addressing the comment consider

- `Valid/Invalid` from cats: https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/validated.html
- define your own ADT with your own meaning of success and failure cases, and then wrap function results in those cases

In neither of these are you forced to use exceptions.

Here is an example

```
sealed trait MyValidationADT[T]
case class Good[T](result: T) extends MyValidationADT[T]
case class Bad[T](result: T) extends MyValidationADT[T]

def foo(i: Int): MyValidationADT[Int] = Bad(42)

foo(11) match {
  case Good(result) => "woohoo"
  case Bad(result) => "boom"
}
```

which outputs

```
res0: String = boom
```

Comment: I already considered using `Either`, but I strongly dislike this construct. Not only because I am dyslexic and the concept of "left" and "right" does not mean anything to me, but as well because it lacks any semantic meaning most of the time.

Comment: Consider defining an ADT, where you can define your own meaning of success and failure cases, and then wrap function results in those cases.

Comment: If you want an ADT that represents the result of a computation that might throw an exception, why not just use `Try`?

Comment: @Tim I believe OP is not interested in exceptions per-se, but semantically more meaningful tags for success and failure. `Try` has those, but force usage of throwables. Perhaps akin to `Valid` and `Invalid` from cats.

Answer (score 3):

It is certainly *possible* to use a `Try` outside an exception context; I use it that way all the time. That does not necessarily mean that it is "acceptable" :)

I would say that the whole point of using `Try` is to take the `Throwable` instance out of the exception context and put it in an object that can be used anywhere in a program. It is hard to see why `Try` would have such a rich set of methods (e.g. `flatMap`) if it is only intended to be used inside an exception context.